# T-SQL JOIN against a Common Table Expression (CTE)

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is it possible to perform a JOIN sub query against a Common Table Expression? If not, then can someone let me know how to perform what I am trying to do below? Examples would be excellent.

For example:

```
LEFT JOIN (

            ;WITH [UserDefined]
                AS (SELECT *, -- Make sure we get only the latest revision.
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]
                                                ORDER BY [RevisionNumber] DESC) AS RN
                    FROM [syn_Change])

            SELECT [UserDefined].[ID]
                ,[UserDefined].[ChangeNumber]
                ,[UserDefined].[Usr_CoResponsibility]
                ,[UserDefined].[Usr_StarFlowStatus]

            FROM [UserDefined]
            WHERE (RN = 1) 

            ) [UserColumns]
ON [UserColumns].[ChangeNumber] = [CTE].[ChangeNumber]
```

Here is my full query:

```
;WITH CTE
    AS (SELECT *, -- Make sure we get only the latest revision.
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemID]
                                    ORDER BY [RevisionNumber] DESC) AS RN
        FROM [dw_Change])

SELECT [CTE].[ItemID]
        ,[CTE].[ViewID]
        ,[CTE].[FolderItemID]
        ,[CTE].[RevisionNumber]
        ,[CTE].[ChangeNumber]
        ,[CTE].[Synopsis]
        ,[CTE].[Description]
        ,[CTE].[EnteredOn]
        ,[CTE].[Responsibility]
        --,[UserColumns].[Usr_CoResponsibility]
        --,[UserColumns].[Usr_StarFlowStatus]
        ,[CTE].[Status] -- This will display the human name on the front-end with code.
        ,[Users].[F7] AS [ResponsibilityName]
        ,[GroupName].[Name] AS [AppGroupName]
        ,[AppName].[Name] AS [AppName]
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN [S3] [Users] ON [Users].[F0] = [CTE].[Responsibility]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Name], [ViewID]
            FROM [dw_Folder]
            WHERE ([FolderItemID] = -1)) [GroupName]
ON [GroupName].[ViewID] = [CTE].[ViewID]

LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Name], [ItemID]
            FROM [dw_Folder]
            WHERE ([FolderItemID] <> -1)) [AppName]
ON [AppName].[ItemID] = [CTE].[FolderItemID]

LEFT JOIN (

            ;WITH [UserDefined]
                AS (SELECT *, -- Make sure we get only the latest revision.
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]
                                                ORDER BY [RevisionNumber] DESC) AS RN
                    FROM [syn_Change])

            SELECT [UserDefined].[ID]
                ,[UserDefined].[ChangeNumber]
                ,[UserDefined].[Usr_CoResponsibility]
                ,[UserDefined].[Usr_StarFlowStatus]

            FROM [UserDefined]
            WHERE (RN = 1) 

            ) [UserColumns]
ON [UserColumns].[ChangeNumber] = [CTE].[ChangeNumber]

WHERE (RN = 1)
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When you define a CTE you're doing so before any of the rest of the query. So you can't write:

```
LEFT JOIN (
  ;WITH CTE
  ...
)
```

As a quick aside, the **reason** people put `;` in front of `WITH` is because all previous statements need to be terminated. If developers could get in the habit of terminating all SQL statements with `;` then it wouldn't be necessary, but I digress...

You can write multiple CTEs like so:

```
WITH SomeCTE AS (
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...
), AnotherCTE AS (
  SELECT ...
  FROM ...
)
SELECT *
FROM SomeCTE LEFT JOIN
     AnotherCTE ON ...
;
```

Comment: And as long as one CTE is defined before others, it can be referred to within the CTEs that follow.

Answer (score 7):

Multiple CTEs need to be declared first. Example:

```
WITH CTE_1 AS
(
    ....
),
CTE_2 AS
(
    ...
)

SELECT        *
FROM          FOO f
LEFT JOIN     CTE_1 c1 ON c1.[SomeCol] = f.[SomeCol]
LEFT JOIN     CTE_2 c2 ON c2.[SomeCol] = f.[SomeCol]
```

Comment: What are you joining on?

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple CTE's, they need to be at the beginning of your statement (comma-separated, and only one `;WITH` to start the list of CTE's):

```
;WITH CTE AS (......),
 [UserDefined] AS (.......)
SELECT.....
```

and then you can use both (or even more than two) in your `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
;
WITH
  RANKED_CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemID] ORDER BY [RevisionNumber] DESC) AS RN
  FROM
    [dw_Change]
)
,
  CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    RANKED_CTE
  WHERE
    RN = 1
)
,
  GroupName AS
(
  SELECT
    [Name], [ViewID]
  FROM
    [dw_Folder]
  WHERE
    ([FolderItemID] = -1)
)
,
  AppName AS
(
  SELECT
    [Name], [ItemID]
  FROM
    [dw_Folder]
  WHERE
    ([FolderItemID] <> -1)
)
SELECT [CTE].[ItemID]
        ,[CTE].[ViewID]
        ,[CTE].[FolderItemID]
        ,[CTE].[RevisionNumber]
        ,[CTE].[ChangeNumber]
        ,[CTE].[Synopsis]
        ,[CTE].[Description]
        ,[CTE].[EnteredOn]
        ,[CTE].[Responsibility]
        --,[UserColumns].[Usr_CoResponsibility]
        --,[UserColumns].[Usr_StarFlowStatus]
        ,[CTE].[Status] -- This will display the human name on the front-end with code.
        ,[Users].[F7] AS [ResponsibilityName]
        ,[GroupName].[Name] AS [AppGroupName]
        ,[AppName].[Name] AS [AppName]
FROM
          CTE
LEFT JOIN [S3] [Users]  ON [Users].[F0] = [CTE].[Responsibility]
LEFT JOIN [GroupName]   ON [GroupName].[ViewID] = [CTE].[ViewID]
LEFT JOIN [AppName]     ON [AppName].[ItemID] = [CTE].[FolderItemID]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple CTEs, I believe; you just have to put them both at the top.

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml):

> You can, however, define multiple CTEs after the WITH keyword by separating each CTE with a comma.